# sqlalchemy map object which contains dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to map an object that looks like this:

```
    self.user = {lots of stuff in here}
    self.timeStamp = i am a date object
    self.coordinates  = {lots of stuff in here}
    self.tweet = {lots of stuff in here}

    self.favourite = 0
    self.reTweet = 0
```

the non dictionaries seem simple to map

```
__tablename__ = 'Tweet'
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
timeStamp = Column(DateTime)
favourite = Column(Integer)
reTweet = Column(Integer)
```

however I have no idea how I can map the dictionary objects. Idealy those objects should proberly go into there own tables so we obey 3rd normal form. However I have no idea where to begin. Can someone point me in the right direction? should I turn these dictionaries into there own objects and map them as well?

many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For storing dictionary objects, you have several options:

- use a [Text](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/core/types.html#sqlalchemy.types.Text) field, write your dict to it via `json.dumps(value)`, read from it using `json.loads(db_value)`
- create your own json [type](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/core/types.html#custom-types), like it was suggested in this thread: [SQLAlchemy JSON as blob/text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038314/sqlalchemy-json-as-blob-text)

  ```
  import jsonpickle
  import sqlalchemy.types as types

  class JsonType(types.MutableType, types.TypeDecorator):    
      impl = types.Unicode

      def process_bind_param(self, value, engine):
          return unicode(jsonpickle.encode(value))

      def process_result_value(self, value, engine):
          if value:
              return jsonpickle.decode(value)
          else:
              # default can also be a list
              return {}
  ```

And, FYI, it would be pretty hard for you to follow 3rd normal form, because tweet objects don't have a strict and defined schema - storing it in the database field is just ok.

By the way, I've found that using [mongodb](http://www.mongodb.org/) for storing tweets is pretty convinient, because it's schemaless and stores json objects.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

The user and co-ordinates entries can be stored as separate tables, which the tweet table will link to as foreign keys. Something like:

```
class Tweet(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tweet'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('tweet_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    user = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    coords = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('coordinates.id'))
    timeStamp = Column(DateTime)
    favourite = Column(Integer)
    reTweet = Column(Integer)

class Coordinates(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'coordinates'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('coordinates_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    lat = ...
    long = ...

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = Column(Integer, Sequence('user_id_seq'), primary_key=True)
    name = ...
```