# Adding, removing, and comparing values to column with Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

SQLAlchemy community, a noob in database and specifically sqlalchemy is seeking your help here. As one would expects, my database consists of rows and columns. Each row is the information about one unique person. Each person has multiple columns (date of birth, name, last name, previous log-in dates, etc.) For one of these columns (previous log-in dates), I would like to store multiple values inside a single cell. In other words, I would like to be able to store the last, let's say ten, log-in dates and be able to manipulate these dates the same way that one would manipulate a list in python. I would like to be able to **append** new log-in dates to this cell, **remove** items from the cell, and **access** specific index of the cell. Basically my cell would like something like this

```
{"04042020","04052020","04072020"}
```

And my database would look like this

```
Name    |   Last Name | Last Log in dates
------------------------------------------------------------
Edgar   |   Allen     |  {"04042020","04052020","04072020"}
Dimitri |  Albertini  |  {"12042019","10112019","01072020"}
```

I know that sqlalchemy has a way of incorporating ARRAYs with

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY
```

After some efforts, I was just merely able to create an ARRAY and I could NOT figure out a way to manipulate(append, remove, access) the array. Here is a simple prototype that create a table with just one column and the element in the first row equals {1,2,3}.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Table, Column, Integer, String, MetaData, ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ARRAY

engine = create_engine('postgresql://rouzbeh:tiger@localhost/newtable')
metadata = MetaData()
newtable = Table("newtable", metadata,
        Column("data", ARRAY(Integer))
    )
metadata.create_all(engine)
connection = engine.connect()
connection.execute(newtable.insert(),data=[1,2,3])
```

Output in Postgress postico looks like the following screenshot. Again to reiterate, I would like to be able to access the elements (`{1,2,3}`) and manipulate them by removing or adding elements to it. (`{1,2,3,4}`) or (`{1,2}`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For a similar use case I am storing such data as JSON. Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4038314/sqlalchemy-json-as-blob-text). The idea is to dump JSON as TEXT (or a JSON object, if your database is supporting this).

For more complex structures I use [Marshmallow](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It's especially useful with nested structures.

However, **this approach is controversial**. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367696/storing-json-in-database-vs-having-a-new-column-for-each-key) and [in this Quora discussion](https://www.quora.com/Why-not-use-relational-databases-to-store-JSON-data-like-a-primary-key-field-and-a-BLOB-field-for-JSON-data-in-a-MySQL-table-instead-of-using-NoSQL-databases-MongoDB-etc). If you can live with the downsides, it is an easy way to store data.

Comment: Yes it does support JSONB. I am running into a new issues which is `sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.DataError) value too long for type character varying(255)`. Basically it is running out of space. I am storing six encrypted values inside the jsonb file. Any suggestion to solve this?