# python sqlalchemy object relational mapping fails because string is expected but dict is provided

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am using sqlalchemy (declarative) to map large amounts of json data to a db table. I have a model like this:

```
class Incident(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'incident'
    sys_id = Column(String(100), primary_key=True)
    state = Column(String)
    assigned_to = Column(String)
```

The data looks like this:

```
{
    "sys_id": "123456"
    "state": "Closed",
    "assigned_to": {
                "display_value": "Fred Bloggs",
                "link": "http://some.url"
            }
}
```

or sometimes like this:

```
{
    "sys_id": "123456"
    "state": "Unassigned",
    "assigned_to": ""
}
```

I get an error because the assigned_to field is sometimes a python dictionary.
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=1 param-type=dict', 'HY105')

I have many fields in the same form as "assigned_to". All I want to do is convert them to strings. I am sure this is saightforward but this is my first exposure to sqlalchemy

Comment: Why not use a JSON column type, rather than String (assuming your RDBMS has such a type)?  Then sqlalchemy will handle serialisation and deserialisation automatically?  Or if you intend to pass only strings, preprocess the data to dump dicts to json?

Comment: looks like I can't use a JSON type: sqlalchemy.exc.CompileError: (in table 'incident', column 'u_contractual_region'): Compiler <sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.base.MSTypeCompiler object at 0x0000020223A3E278> can't render element of type <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.JSON'>

Comment: Some of the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4038314/5320906) may be useful.